# Mongodb replicaset on docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-replica-set

I wrote a docker compose file to run a replica set for mongodb I changes all the permission for the key file and on have read permission but stillhave this issue

```
{"code":30,"codeName":"InvalidPath","errmsg":"permissions on /keyfile/mongo-keyfile are too open"}}}
```

Docker compose file :

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo1-data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-keyfile:/keyfile/mongo-keyfile
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=adminpassword
    command: "--replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all --keyFile /keyfile/mongo-keyfile"

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo2-data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-keyfile:/keyfile/mongo-keyfile
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=adminpassword
    command: "--replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all --keyFile /keyfile/mongo-keyfile"

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo3-data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-keyfile:/keyfile/mongo-keyfile
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=adminpassword
    command: "--replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all --keyFile /keyfile/mongo-keyfile"

volumes:
  mongo1-data:
  mongo2-data:
  mongo3-data:
```

Working folder on the screenshot:

[image]

running Mongodb replicaset on docker

Comment: The read permission must apply only to the user where mongod is running, nobody else.